# How to stop Jest from hanging when testing WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ws

I created an app in node.js which gives me a WebSocket interface using the 'ws' package from NPM on the server. Now I want to test this interface with Jest. The test runs successful but Jest does not exit and gives me the error:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

I read the documentation and found that I have to use the `done` parameter in the test and call it when the test has finished.

The server will be started in the `beforeAll` function and stopped in the `afterAll` function given by Jest.

```js
describe('app', () => {
    it('connect websockets response' (done), => {
        expect.assertions(1);

        new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:${port}`).on('message' (msg), => {
                expect(JSON.parse(msg).id).toEqual(0);
                done();
            })
    });
});
```

I expect that Jest stops successful after the test has finished.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have learned that I have to close the WebSocket connection in the test itself, and wait for the closing event.

```
describe('app', () => {
    it('connect websockets response', (done) => {
        expect.assertions(1);

        const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:${port}`)
            .on('message', (msg) => {
                expect(JSON.parse(msg).id).toEqual(0);
                ws.close();
            })
            .on('close', () => done());
    });
});
```

Comment: do you have an example repro?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini Sorry i don't have an example repo. It's all company code on private machines. Therefore i can't share more than this. What exactly do you need it for? Can i help you in other ways?

Comment: I tried this solution *exact same structure and it just works.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me using TypeScript

```
  test('connect websockets response', (done) => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:${port}`);

    const listener = (msg: MessageEvent) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(msg.data));
      // Put you expect statement here
      ws.removeEventListener('message', listener);
      ws.close();
    };

    ws.addEventListener('message', listener);

    ws.addEventListener('close', () => done());
  }, 30000);
```